# How to Redirect to user profile in django? i am using Django registration Redux

Tags: django, django-registration

I am working on an app where the user will be able to login to his profile. I am using Django-registration-redux. I am using the below code to inculde in my project.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile/view/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/'
```

I want to redirect the user to his profile after logging in. I know that is not the way you can actually call an url in settings file. any solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy to add URL resolution to a setting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the user pk to the view. You can get this value and every other data field of the user from *request.user* object.

As stated in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user), you could do something like this:

```
def profile(request):    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Do something for logged-in users.
        request.user.do_something()
    [...]
    else:
        # Do something for anonymous users like redirect to registration 
        pass
```